# TypeORM Error sending information to the database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

When trying to make a request using postman, my console returns the error:

(node:25151) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

Apparently I can create the tables in the database, but I can't send the requests.

```
import app from './app';
import { AppDataSource } from './src/database/Config';

async function connection() {
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    try {
        await AppDataSource.initialize();
        console.log('Database connected! ');
        app.listen(port);
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

connection();
```

controller:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";

import { User } from "../entities/User";

class UserController {
    async store(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const repository = getRepository(User);
        const { email, username, password } = req.body;

        const userExists = await repository.findOne({ where: { email } });

        if (userExists) {
            return res.status(409).json('User already exists');
        }

        const user = repository.create({ email, username, password });
        await repository.save(user);

        return res.status(200).json(user);
    }
}

export default new UserController();
```

config database

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { User } from "../entities/User"

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: 5432,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [User],
    subscribers: [],
    migrations: [],
})
```

Comment: From the docs it appears that you'll need to use `AppDataSource.getRepository(User);`, not just `getRepository(User);`. Or you'll need to find some way to register that `AppDataSource` as the default datasource for repositories created using plain `getRepository`, unfortunately the docs are silent about that.

Comment: Now for some reason it is returning " throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')"

Comment: Then maybe you have a problem with `process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD`